# Accessing environment variables in Python created by C shell script

Tags: python, environment-variables, csh

I have some hard time to access environment variables in a Python script but those environment variables are created by a C shell script. To further elaborate my question, this is what I am doing:

```
call.subprocess(['csh_script_that_sets_envar_abc.csh'])

print os.environ.get("abc")
```

Result:

```
None
```

Why can't the C shell script set the environment in the Python script.

Comment: You can't. An environment variable is set for the current process & all subprocesses. You can't just set the environment of other random processes. You will need to communicate the value as output, or use some other form of IPC such as a socket.

Answer (score 2):

Succinctly, there isn't a reasonable way for a child process (the C shell script) to set the environment variable in the parent process (the Python code).  Child processes cannot affect the parent like that.

It isn't peculiar to Python or C shell per se; it is a property of parent and child processes on Unix-like systems.